# calling async method in parallel c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, async-await, task

I have a method which takes a `int` input and return `Task<Dictionary<DateTime, HistPrice>>`

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<DateTime, HistPrice>> GetPrices(int seriesId) {
    ...
    return Dictionary<DateTime, HistPrice>;
}
```

Now I want to call the above method for list of values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 in parallel.

```
List<int> seriesIdDist = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 });

var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var t in seriesIdDist) {
    tasks.Add(GetPrices(t));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Till here everything is working fine, problem is in extracting the result from the task. I tried to extract the result like

```
foreach(var ta in tasks) {
    var res = await ta;//error in this line
}
```

but it says

> CS0815    Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
```

Use this instead:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<Dictionary<DateTime, HistPrice>>>();
```

Or replace it *and your foreach loop* with a little bit of LINQ, which saves you from having to worry about the type.

```
var tasks = seriesIdDist.Select( n => GetPrices(n) ).ToList();
```